# how to make the data-table plugins working properly>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use data-tables plug-ins for my tables but it's doesnt work

i've tried some answer in this site but still doesnt work

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and this the tables

```php
<table id="example" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered text-center">

            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Id Transaksi</th>
                <th>No Kuitansi</th>
                <th>Nama Barang</th>
                <th>Kuantitas</th>
                <th>Harga</th>
                <th>Tanggal</th>
                <th>Keterangan</th>
                <th colspan="2">Opsi</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                    $list = stokORM::find_many();
                    $i=1;
                    foreach($list as $stk) :
                        $brg = $stk->barang()->find_one();
                        $trx = $stk->transaksi()->find_one();
                ?>
                <?php
                    $tgl = new carbon($trx->tanggal);
                 ?>
                     <tr>
                    <td><?= $i++;?></td>
                    <td><?= $stk->trx13_id;?></td>
                    <td><?= $trx->no_kuitansi;?></td>
                    <td><a href="lihat_perbarang.php?id=<?= $brg->id;?>">
                            <?= $brg->nama;?></td>
                    <td><?= $stk->qty.' '.$brg->satuan;?></td>
                    <?php
                      if($trx->jenisTrx == 0){
                        echo "<td>".rupiah($trx->hargaJual)."</td >";
                      } else {
                        echo "<td>".rupiah($trx->harga)."</td>";
                      }
                     ?>
                    <td><?= $tgl->format('d/m/Y');?></td>
                    <td><?php
                        if($stk->jenisTrx == 0){
                            echo "Penjualan";
                        } else {
                            echo "Pembelian";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <?php
                    if($stk->jenisTrx == 0) {
                      echo "<td colspan='2'><a style='color:blue;' href='laba-rugi.php?id=$brg->id'>
                      Cek Laba Rugi
                    </a></td>";
                    } else {
                    echo "<td><a style='color:blue;'href='jual-barang.php?id=$trx->id'>
                      Jual
                    </a></td>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <?php endforeach;?>
          </table>
```

and the script in the end

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

i want it to work properly,like i can doing live search i can sort record,and pagination
sorry for my bad english.
thanks in advance

Comment: can you try putting `<?php endforeach;?>` before tbody closing?

Comment: Also you may have different number of cells between `thead` and `tbody` in some cases (when `$stk->jenisTrx !== 0` particularly).

Comment: @Sanjundev i've try it,but nothing happen still same error,but it's solve now it's because my colspan,thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete colspan="2" from

`<th colspan="2">Opsi</th>`

The second step is going to F12 and look at Console, you should see your errors. If it's so, please, give this information below.

Comment: thanks,it's work properly now,so it's because my colspan,does data-tables can't work with colspan?

Comment: DataTables would be applied to the table if the number of columns will be the same in thead and in tbody and in tfoot, because it has one special ability - to sort column by clicking on it thead, script won't sort the column if thead has 2 columns. So, yes, DT can't work with colspan in thead.